# Why does my Pycharm Project not see folder? FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'

Tags: pycharm

```
# load table
with open(os.path.join('../input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'), mode='r') as infile:
```

I got an error in my Pycharm Project: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'`

[Pycharm Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krTC4.png)

edit:
If I put full path, it works correctly:
`with open(os.path.join('/home/wojtek/PycharmProjects/untitled3/venv/input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'), mode='r') as infile:`

Comment: From which file are you trying to refrence stage_2_train_labels.csv?

Comment: yes from stage_2_tranin_labels.csv

Comment: you are referencing a file inside the same file? reference from `stage_2_train_labels.csv` to `'../input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'`?? Which is your working file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly. You are trying to access the `stage_2_train_labels.csv` from the root of the project which is `ww.py` You dont need to use `../` as you are in the root of the project.

This should be changed

```
with open(os.path.join('../input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'), mode='r') as infile:
```

To this

```
with open(os.path.join('input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'), mode='r') as infile:
```

or if you are trying to access the file in the venv folder change to

```
with open(os.path.join('venv/input/stage_2_train_labels.csv'), mode='r') as infile:
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extension of your file name, should be good to go!

Comment: In this way: 
`with open(os.path.join('../input/stage_2_train_labels'), mode='r') as infile:`

But it didn't help:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../input/stage_2_train_labels'`

Comment: Alright! In your Pycharm IDE right click on your file and select **"Copy Path"**, then you can paste it in some editor to check if you are in the right directory in the first place. It seems that there is something wrong with your path.